# Output of "rowsimilarity" is different for each run

Tags: mahout

Mahout: The output of rowsimilarity process is different in each run of below mentioned steps (keeping all input same for all run)

Step1: seq2sparse        (Creating vectors from text)
Step2: rowid                   (generate tfidf vectors)
Step3: rowsimilarity       (calculate similarity between vectors)
Step4: seqdumper         (binary vectors to text)

UPDATE:

Thanks Pferrel for the reply,
Kindly suggest how can we specify the "seed value"

The commands which I am using are:
${MAHOUT_HOME}/bin/mahout seq2sparse -i ${DATA}/seq-data -o ${DATA}/vectors -n 2 -wt tfidf -ng 3 -nv -ow -md 100 -s 10

${MAHOUT_HOME}/bin/mahout rowid -i ${DATA}/vectors/tfidf-vectors/part-r-00000 -o ${DATA}/matrix

${MAHOUT_HOME}/bin/mahout rowsimilarity -i ${DATA}/matrix/matrix -o ${DATA}/similarity  --similarityClassname SIMILARITY_COSINE -m 100 -ess -ow

Answer (score 0):

The data is randomly downsampled so set the seed to a fixed value if you want repeatability. You can also set the downsampling to kick in at a large number of items to disable it, but be aware that this will make it run slower, the speed will approach O(n^2).

Comment: Hi pferrel thanks for ur answer, please find my updates in question and kindly suggest how to set "seed value"    (We are using Mahout 0.9 version)

Comment: The seed is used as a "seed" for a random sampling and is used only if you want completely reproducible results. Otherwise there will be some slight variation in results based on the random sampling.

Item similarity is only used for collaborative filtering reasons and down-sample the data to keep the calculations at O(n) and after a point the data yields diminishing returns. BTW there is a new Spark version that run 10x faster in Mahout 0.11.x here http://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/intro-cooccurrence-spark.html

Comment: For collaborative filtering the Log-Likelihood Ratio (LLR) works better than Cosine in every case i've tried.